# can't assign a string to a worksheet cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a weird problem in my VBA code.

When I try to assign an integer it works fine

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.name).Cells(1, 2).value = 5
```

but when I try to assign a string

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.name).Cells(1, 2).value = "Hello"
```

I've this error

[image]

Comment: That error doesn't seem to match the line of code. What other code do you have in the workbook?

Comment: Please press "Débogage", which line of code gets highlighted?

Comment: The error might be on a preceding or following line of code; adding a little context would be useful. It might also be worth checking what cells reference the cell you're updating.

Comment: the proble is in this line ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.name).Cells(1, 2).value = "Hello" because when I use ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.name).Cells(1, 3).value = "Hello" it works 1 there is a problem with the second cell ! but I don't see where !

Comment: We need more detail than this. We're not going be able to reproduce based on the info you've provided.